# writing a batch file that opens a chrome URL

Tags: batch-file

looking for some help writing a batch file to use as a joke on my friend. essentially i want it to open a certain URL in chrome. then i was going to disguise it as something like svchost.exe and have it run at startup on a timer.
thanks a lot!

Comment: well i've never written batch before so I was looking for someone to help me start to finish on the actual code

Comment: A more interesting idea would be to change his desktop background to an image from this site, every time he logs on.

Comment: Tip: google `chrome command line`

Answer (score 99):

It's very simple. Just try:

```
start chrome https://www.google.co.in/
```

it will open the Google page in the Chrome browser.

If you wish to open the page in Firefox, try:

```
start firefox https://www.google.co.in/
```

Have Fun!

Comment: I just tried this, for me it open up an endless stream of cmd-prompts

Comment: @paK0 are you trying this command from run prompt, command prompt or a batch file?

Comment: @RBT batch file

Answer (score 18):

assuming chrome is his default browser:  `start http://url.site.you.com/path/to/joke`  should open that url in his browser.

Comment: This is the best answer, unless it must run in chrome which I wouldn't assume is the case.

Answer (score 10):

```
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2"

start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"

start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 3"

start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/"

@ECHO OFF
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
```