# redirect user from Internet explorer to Chome on php/html website

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-platform

so my file does not work properly if it is on I.E <11 so I want to redirect the user to a chrome broswer and/or provide a hyperlink to take them to chrome if they are on I.E  how would I do that?

Comment: You are just going to have to show a big message saying dont use I.E. Think what would happen if you could decide what I run on my PC. Madness I tell you, madness

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611172/launch-chrome-browser-from-internet-explorer , but i don't think that's a good idea .

Comment: _"I want to redirect the user to a chrome broswer"_ - What if they don't have chrome or don't want to use it? Also, how big of an issue is this really? There aren't really that many people that uses IE 10 and lower.

Comment: That's why I mention provide a or provide hyperlink to google chrome.

Comment: That won't help with the _"or don't want to use it"_. Do you have any real stats how many of your users actually uses IE 10 or lower? Btw, IE10 is officially unsupported since January this year. Either way, if you do some research, you will find that there are plenty of articles about detecting IE10 and lower. Start there and make some attempts.

Comment: yes but most companies still use it. I want it so that if I were to make something for a comany one day they will be able to use it. I am using this as a learning process so when I work for a company that uses IE < 11 I will know how to do it

Comment: also quick question if my program works for IE11 does that imply that it will work for IE 12, 13, etc

Comment: i mean in the future. and lots of banks still use internet legacy stuff

Comment: First [IE 11 is the last planned first of IE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#End_of_life), so don't worry about IE 12 and on. Second, you create a link to Chrome the same way that you create a link to format someone's hard drive. Wait, you can do that? **No**. Linking to another program from the web is not a thing, and any attempts to do so will be blocked at best, or trigger AV issues. You _could_ create a plugin for IE, force users to download and install the plugin, and for those users do something special, but it is so not worth it in 2020.

Comment: thankyou for your comment. This was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

A browser cannot launch any other applications on the machine.

I also agree with the suggestions to identify the browser and display the message that this version of the IE browser is not supported.

There are some ways like modifying the registry or by using the batch file or using the custom protocol handler to launch the Chrome browser but these are not the suitable solutions as you need to implement it on each machine.

So most suitable workaround is to inform the users of using the supported browsers by your web app.